# flutter web audio not working after deployment

Tags: flutter, web, audio, deployment

```
  void listenToOrderChanges() {
    CollectionReference reference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('orders');
    orderSubscription = reference.snapshots().listen((querySnapshot) {
      final addedChanges = querySnapshot.docChanges.where((change) => change.type == DocumentChangeType.added).toList();
      if (isFirstLaunch) {
        isFirstLaunch = false;
      } else if (addedChanges.isNotEmpty) {
        // Play alert sound
        html.AudioElement audioElement = html.AudioElement('assets/mixkit.wav');
        audioElement.play();

        // Show Snackbar
        Get.snackbar('New order added', 'alert');
      }
    });
  }
```

Im trying to get sound with snackbar when new document add to the collection using flutter web and it works fine before deployment but after deployment it gives snakbar without sound.

I've tried many packages but all have same issue

Answer (score 0):

i used this package https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayer and worked for web

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
```

code:

```
AudioPlayer player = AudioPlayer();
String audioasset = "assets/sound/bell-dinging-jam-fx-2-2-00-05.mp3";

ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load(audioasset); //load sound from assets

Uint8List soundbytes = bytes.buffer.asUint8List(bytes.offsetInBytes, bytes.lengthInBytes);

final urlSource = UrlSource(Uri.dataFromBytes(soundbytes, mimeType:'audio/mpeg').toString());

player.play(urlSource);
```